# Granting script under a SecurityManager to access system properties

Tags: java, securitymanager, accesscontrolexception

I want to allow scripts in a sandbox to access system properties but I get `AccessControlException`s. Here is the code:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.security.AccessControlContext;
import java.security.AccessController;
import java.security.CodeSource;
import java.security.Permission;
import java.security.Permissions;
import java.security.PrivilegedAction;
import java.security.ProtectionDomain;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.util.PropertyPermission;
import org.junit.Test;

public class AccessControlTest {

    @Test
    public void testAccessControl() throws Exception {

        PrivilegedAction<String> action = new PrivilegedAction<String>() {

            @Override
            public String run() {
                System.getProperty( "java.version" ); // doesn't work
                return System.getProperty( "foo" ); // doesn't work
            }
        };


        SecurityManager sm = new SecurityManager() {
            @Override
            public void checkPermission( Permission perm ) {

                if( "setSecurityManager".equals( perm.getName() ) ) {
                    return;
                }

                System.out.println( perm );
                super.checkPermission( perm );
            }
        };

        Permissions perms = new Permissions();
        perms.add( new PropertyPermission( "foo", "read" ) );
//        perms.add( new PropertyPermission( "java.version", "read" ) );

        ProtectionDomain domain = new ProtectionDomain( new CodeSource( null, (Certificate[]) null ), perms );
        AccessControlContext context = new AccessControlContext( new ProtectionDomain[] { domain } );

        try {
            System.setSecurityManager( sm );

            Object result = AccessController.doPrivileged( action, context );
            assertEquals( Boolean.TRUE, result );
        } finally {
            System.setSecurityManager( null );
            System.out.println( "setSecurityManager( null )" );
        }


    }

}
```

When debugging this, I see this output:

```
...
policy:   granting (java.lang.RuntimePermission stopThread)
policy:   granting (java.net.SocketPermission localhost:1024- listen,resolve)
policy:   granting (java.util.PropertyPermission java.version read)
...
(java.util.PropertyPermission java.version read)
java.lang.Exception: Stack trace
    at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Thread.java:1249)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:323)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:549)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
    at com.avanon.script.AccessControlTest$2.checkPermission(AccessControlTest.java:39)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(SecurityManager.java:1285)
    at java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:650)
...
access: domain 0 ProtectionDomain  (null <no signer certificates>)
 null
 <no principals>
 java.security.Permissions@78ce5b1c (
 (java.util.PropertyPermission foo read)
)


access: domain 1 ProtectionDomain  (file:/.../project/target-eclipse/test-classes/ <no signer certificates>)
 sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5d0385c1
 <no principals>
 java.security.Permissions@6ddf073d (
 (java.io.FilePermission /.../project/target-eclipse/test-classes/- read)
 (java.lang.RuntimePermission exitVM)
)


access: access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission java.version read)
```

(invoke the code with `-Djava.security.debug=all` to get the same output)

The first block comes from the global `java.policy` file that comes with the JRE.

Next block is when the code tried to check the access to `java.version`.

The last block shows that this fails.

This surprised me because access to the propery is allowed in the policy file.

To help, I enabled the commented out line which adds `PropertyPermission` for `java.version`. Now the first `System.getProperty( "java.version" )` passes.

But the second one still fails:

```
access: domain that failed ProtectionDomain  (file:/.../project/target-eclipse/test-classes/ <no signer certificates>)
 sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5d0385c1
 <no principals>
 java.security.Permissions@6ddf073d (
 (java.io.FilePermission /.../project/target-eclipse/test-classes/- read)
 (java.lang.RuntimePermission exitVM)
)
```

I'm really stumped by this. From the code, it seems that Java always checks all `ProtectionDomain`s in order (I have four). If any of them doesn't like your access, it will be denied.

But I don't see how the second domain allows access to any properties, so I was expecting either both to fail or both to succeed.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look in `ProtectionDomain.implies()`:

```
if (!staticPermissions && 
    Policy.getPolicyNoCheck().implies(this, permission))
    return true;
```

This means that for dynamic `ProtectionDomain`s, the current `Policy` is applied. When a `SecurityManager` is installed, the default policy is loaded with some grants that give access to the system properties.

To enable the same for your `ProtectionDomain`, you need to use a different constructor:

```
    public ProtectionDomain(CodeSource codesource,
            PermissionCollection permissions,
            ClassLoader classloader,
            Principal[] principals)
```

This will get you half-way: The access to the system property will now pass.

But the second access to the property `foo` will pass for the first protection domain and fail for the others.

To fix this, you will have to install your own default policy which allows access to both `java.version` and `foo`.

If you do this, then you don't need a custom `ProtectionDomain` anymore; the policy will be enough.